# The WKB approximation and the Cotangent bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, quantization, semiclassical

When we say (see pag. 9 of [Lectures on the Geometry of Quantization](https://math.berkeley.edu/~alanw/GofQ.pdf)) that

> the image of the differential of the phase function lies in the level set of the classical Hamiltonian

is it simply equivalent to reading the following equation?

$$H(x,S'(x)) = E$$

i.e. to applying the inverse Hamiltonian $H^{-1}$ operator to both members?

In which way is relevant that the cotangent bundle (or the dual of the tangent bundle)  $T^*M$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Is that isomorphism (together with $dS: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow T^*\mathbb{R}$) taken into consideration to replace $p$ with $S'$ or has it to do with the exponential map between the Lie algebra (as tangent space) and the Lie group or maybe with the de Rahm cohomology: when we say

> "*the Chern class of the line bundle $L$*"

is $L={\rm Im}(dS)$ an $n$-dimensional submanifold of $H^{-1}(E)$ and so is it the so-called "*level manifold/set*" or something else unrelated?

This is what I've tried to study more from a mathematical standpoint, of course I'd like to put it into a physical perspective.

Comment: $L = \mathrm{im}(dS)$ stands for a Lagrangian submanifold. It has a dimension of $\dim(T^*M)/2= \dim(M)$. The line bundle $L$ in this context, usually denotes a line bundle over the cotangent bundle $T^*M$ it has a dimension of $2\dim(M)+1$. They are not the same object.

Comment: Not exactly the same object, but, for example, in the quantization context, I think we can define the Maslov line bundle of a Lagrangian submanifold...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the importance of the diffeomorphism on points in configuration space is that the cotangent lift (see 6.3 of [Cotangent Bundles](https://www.math.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/~jnatar/MG-03/Marsden/ms_book_ch6.pdf)) $T^*f$ is guaranteed to be symplectic. If $M$ is a cotangent bundle $T^*Q$ then the obvious choice for the pre quantum bundle $B$ is $M \times\mathbb{C}$. Indeed in the prequantization we introduce the polarization by requiring that $q$ goes to $\frac {\partial} {\partial p}$

> A symplectic manifold (M,ω) is said to be *prequantizable* if the
>   integral of $\omega$ around any 2-cycle lies in $2\pi\mathbb{Z}$

Now given the Lie Algebra $\mathfrak{h}$ of a compact and connected Lie group $H$, the character group $\hat H$ can be identified with $H^1(H,\mathbb{Z})$. The Maslov class of a lagrangian immersion $\iota: L → T^∗M$ is defined as the degree-1 cohomology class and determines via the exponential map $\mathbb{R} \to U(1)$ an isomorphism class of flat hermitian line bundles over $L$ (see pag. 56 of the pdf linked in the question).

Another way of looking at this is that if we impose the strong Legendre condition, that $\mathscr L$ is globally a diffeomorphism, then Lagrange’s equations on $TQ$ are transfromed by $\mathscr L$ into Hamilton’s equations on $T^∗Q$ with canonical symplectic structure.

Finally, given a Lagrangian submanifold $\Lambda$ of the cotangent bundle, contained in the energy shell $H^{-1}(E)$, it is desirable to attach the WKB expansion to the manifold  $\Lambda$ (see [Semi-classical approximations](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIHPA_1976__24_1_31_0.pdf))

> The WKB method applies when the semi-classical density in phase space
>   is supported by a Lagrangian submanifold: for the levels of a
>   separable system this leads to the Bohr-Sommerfeld rules corrected by
>   the Maslov index.

And that corresponds to the Maslov quantization condition, described in the already mentioned [Lectures on the Geometry of Quantization](https://math.berkeley.edu/~alanw/GofQ.pdf) at pag. 45

> Returning to the harmonic oscillator of Example 4.5, we see that the
>   level set $H^{−1}(E)$ satisfies the Maslov condition provided that for
>   some integer n, $E = (n + 1/2)$. Allowable energy levels in this case
>   therefore correspond to the Bohr-Sommerfeld condition, which actually
>   gives the precise energy levels for the quantum harmonic oscillator.